# How to track the each operation of the MS Access database using java

Tags: java, database, ms-access

**We want to use the MS Access Database file to be tracked while CRUD (Create,Read,Update,Delete) operations occurs on it.**

How to track the CRUD Operations using JAVA while I do have full URL String for database connection ?

How to know which type of queries are being fired on database ?

For example:

*User A fires queries of insert,update or delete operations on DB then user B will be notified that user A changed the database.*

In short how to get updates from the  **MS Access**  database using java ?

I just know how to work with CRUD operations on MS Access but HERE I can not use logging or maintain history.

I am using Database file ACCDB or MDB anyone of these.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would achieve such goal by not permitting your users to connect directly to the database. Instead, you would provide them with a CRUD service. Here are some basic tutorial on RESTful CRUD services in Java.

http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/RESTfulWebServices/RESTfulWebservices.htm

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html

http://persistentdesigns.com/wp/rest-crud-jersey-spring-and-jpa/

Note that these tutorials are not specific to MS Access database. You just need to change the bit that describes the database connectivity. Here's some help on how you would connect to MS Access database from Java

http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/03/ms-access-database-connectivity-in-java.html#.VABXO_42W3Q

Comment: Wooo wo wo Dear user @bpgergo I said I just want to track MS ACCESS I know I can use periodic comparison to know database changes but Here I want to check with the some different way just like trigger fires on database side and java track them but here I don't know what to do to track them without trigger and without periodic updates comparison BTW thanks for your opinion.

Comment: I may have not made myself clear. My proposed solution does not involve neither periodic comparison, nor triggers. It is the CRUD service implemented in Java, that will log all CRUD operations.